# Capturing `self` within willSet

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a collection view delegate helper class with a property that looks like:

```
weak var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate? {
    willSet {
        self.collectionView?.delegate = newValue
    }
}
```

will `self` ever be captured inside the `willSet` block?

Unlike other blocks, you can't do `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` on the will set block. In cases where I had `collectionView?.delegate =` and self.collectionView?.delegate = `,`deinit`was always called, indicating to me that it doesn't make a difference whether or not`self` is used inside a setter block.

Comment: Excellent! If you put that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a [property observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262), not a block which means it doesn't retain/copy/capture any object so you can safely use `self` in there.

By the way, I would implement getter and setter for that variable instead because you defined it just to be able to update the collectionView's delegate property:

```
weak var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate? {
  get {
    return self.collectionView?.delegate
  }
  set {
    self.collectionView?.delegate = newValue
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, I'll be sure to do that. Do the property observer rules also apply to `get` and `set` blocks?

Comment: Yes, they do. They are not blocks at all.

Comment: Is that just syntax that the complier recognizes as something separate than blocks?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A block has a type and is defined with either `var` or `let` keyword just like a regular variable.

Comment: Hi @Ozgur. I can't see any documentation in the 'property observer' link you shared here, that supports your claim that these are not blocks or that self is not captured. That being said I do believe you, but I was hoping to find some supporting evidence. Do you have any other links?